# Raspbian Recovery Mode withought NOOBS

Tags: raspbian

I have raspberry pi with Raspbian installed in it. I want to switch into recovery mode. I haven't installed NOOBS and do not want to use it any way.
How can I move into recovery mode of raspbian.

Comment: What makes you think there is a "recovery mode of Raspberry Pi"? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, I meant recovery mode of "Raspbian". I want to do firmware upgrade over the air (FOTA) of raspbian. And since to upgrade the raspbian, I would require it to boot into recovery mode of "Raspbian".

Comment: There is no such thing.

Comment: There is nothing like "Recovery Mode of Raspian" ? If is it so then how can I add/modify/delete filesystem of Raspbian (for updating purpose) while it is running. ?

Comment: I think it would be beneficial if you would try to explain what problem you are trying to solve. What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: I will explain my objective:
I wish to upgrade Raspbian version say X.4 to X.5 while raspbian is running.
I have only delta package between X.4 & X.5 (i.e. only the modified files & new files & folders and list of files that has been deleted). Now using this Delta package I want to upgrade Raspbian X.4 to version X.5 while raspbian is running.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to boot your pi to recovery mode for upgrading the OS. 
To upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

A summary and further details [can be found here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md).